# cuInit(0) not needed anymore?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm currently writing an app to stream openGL content, therefore using CUDA with NVidias NVenc-API. I have noticed that calling `cuInit(0)` - which should be done as a first call to initialize Cuda, according to many tutorials, does not change the success of my Cuda Kernel. So whether I'm calling it or not, the program runs in both scenarios.

Have they changed it? I was looking for some information but could not find anything about this.

Thanks!

A bit more information:

First step is to create a Cuda Device using `cudaSetDevice()` - Runtime API.
Second step, create a context using `cuCtxCreate()` - Driver API.
After this I can launch a kernel using triple chevron syntax with a cuda array allocated via `cudaMalloc()`.

Comment: Are you using the CUDA driver or runtime API ?

Comment: Both APIs do work.

Comment: That isn't  what I asked. Does your code use the runtime API or the driver API? NVenc itself has nothing to do with CUDA and doesn't require a CUDA context to run.

Comment: Ok, so I think because I am launching the kernel with <<<>>>, it is the runtime API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first call in your code is, as you say, `cudaSetDevice()`, and your CUDA version is CUDA 4 or newer, then that will implicitly establish a context, and there is no requirement to do anything else to make a CUDA runtime API session work correctly.

You should *not* call `cuCtxCreate` or `cuInit` after that. If you have a genuine requirement to use both the runtime and driver APIs (and it doesn't sound like you do), there is a [supported and documented](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interoperability-between-runtime-and-driver-apis) method for doing so. The rule of thumb is to use *either* the driver API *or* the runtime API, but not, both, and if you don't have a reason to use the driver API, then don't use it. The runtime API is simpler, cleaner and less verbose.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So if I need a handle to a valid CudaContext I have to use the driver api and omit, at best, every call to the runtime api?

Comment: No. If you need driver API features, it is still OK to mix the APIs, but follow the process described in the link in my answer: use the driver API to create the context, then use the runtime API after that (and you must call `cuInit(0)` as the first call in such a usage case)